# php mysql comparing data

Tags: php, mysql

OK i have this code:

```
<?//admin
$host = 'localhost'; // Host name Normally 'LocalHost'
$user = 'root'; // MySQL login username
$pass = ''; // MySQL login password
$database = 'juliver'; // Database name
$table = 'admin'; // Members name

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($database);
if (isset($_POST['acc']) && ($_POST['pass']))
{
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acc']);
$password = hash('sha512', $_POST['pass']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password =     '$password'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
  // Login
echo "has been login";
}
else
{
  // Invalid username/password
  echo 'Error: Invalid username or password';
}

exit;

}
else
{
echo "not been set";
}
?>
```

and i got this error: "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mu2\admin.php on line 17
has been login", can somebody around here, could help me to figure out what might the hell is that error please?.. thanks in advance

im open in any suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple your call to mysql_query fails, You can `echo mysql_error()` right after it to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your MySQL query you might be accessing something that isn't there or misspelling something. Echoing mysql_error() will tell you your problem. I would also recommend eliminating the extra spaces in your query (it look a little odd). :)

Answer (score 0):

This would help you find the error

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
$host = 'localhost'; // Host name Normally 'LocalHost'
$user = 'root'; // MySQL login username
$pass = ''; // MySQL login password
$database = 'juliver'; // Database name
$table = 'admin'; // Members name

$link = mysql_connect ( $host, $user, $pass );

if (! $link) {
    die ( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error ());
}

$selected = mysql_select_db ( $database );

if (! $selected) {
    die ( 'Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error ());
}

if (isset ( $_POST ['acc'] ) && ($_POST ['pass'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['acc'] );
    $password = hash ( 'sha512', $_POST ['pass'] );

    $result = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password =  '$password'" );

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        // Login
        echo "has been login";
    } else {
        // Invalid username/password
        echo 'Error: Invalid username or password';
    }

    exit ();

} else {
    echo "not been set";
}
```